# How to differentiate the click function for nested element tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have two elements which are nested and I want to make two click functions. My body tag is for a complete page and I have a button tag which is inside the body tag.

When the user clicks the button I want to add text in my input textbox. When the user clicks outside of the button, which is inside body tag I have to remove text from the textbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert("only button is clicked");
    $("input:text").val("Test");
  });

  $("body").click(function() {
    alert("body clicked");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="setName" value="" /><br/><br/><br/>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736102/157247) is spot-on (as usual). Another option is to just use one handler on `body` and use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to figure out whether the click passed through the button en route to body, see comments:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").click(function(e) {
    // Did this click pass through the button?
    if ($(e.target).closest("button").length) {
      // Yes
      alert("only button is clicked");
      $("input:text").val("Test");
    } else {
      // No
      alert("body clicked");
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="setName" value="" /><br/><br/><br/>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution instead of using `e.stopPropagation()` function.

Answer (score 7):

While it's possible to identify the clicked element in the `body` click handler, it would be much easier to just call `stopPropagation()` within the `button` click handler to stop the event bubbling at all:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("only button is clicked");
    $("input:text").val("Test");
  });

  $("body").click(function() {
    console.log("body clicked");
    $("input:text").val(''); // add this line to remove the text
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="setName" value="" /><br/><br/><br/>
<button>Set the value of the input field</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track the target of whichever element clicked via event.target and then perform the requisite operation

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="container">   
    <input type="text" id="setName" value="" />
    <button id="samplebtn">Set the value of the input field</button>
</body>


$("body").click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id == "samplebtn") {
        //do button related work
    } else {
        //do other stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: That's what [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52736193/157247) does, except this doesn't allow for the fact that `button` elements can have elements inside them (for instance: `<button><em>Emphasized Button</em></button>`). That's why I used `closest`. :-)

Comment: What if the button gets changed to some input type, say textbox. Will that work then?

Comment: Yes. `closest` [starts with the element itself](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). If you mean would it keep working even if you didn't change its selector, then no, of course it wouldn't. Just like one relying on an `id` won't work if you change the `id`. If you make a fundamental change, you need to handle that change throughout.

Comment: DOM Manipulations are largely done on the basis of attributes in a html element. Assume of an agile methodology which totally start relying on the "type" of html element, then, I will have to make multiple changes and go through all those iterations.

Comment: In my experience, there's no basis for that statement whatsoever. Whatever. Happy coding.